# Error: The type or namespace name 'fileInfoNew' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code gives me the error

> Error: The type or namespace name 'fileInfoNew' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried to add resource EntityFramework but that comes up with the error:

> The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found.

## Failing Code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_18ff7a6acad54a089ed1d4a93700a713.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

    enum ScriptResults 
    { 
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success, 
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure 
    }; 

        public void Main()
        {
            string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables["Y:\\Monoday\\Rachael\\PromasterFiles\\Partners YTD Promaster Monthly Transaction list.xlsx"].Value.ToString()); 
            DateTime highestDate = new DateTime();             
            int lastDate = 01/07/11 ;
            int fileInfo;
            int fileInfoNew;                                                                                                                                                    
            Boolean runPackage = false;

            foreach (string currentFile in sourceFiles)             
            {                                  
                fileInfo = new fileInfoNew(currentFile);                                                  
                
                if (fileInfo > lastDate)                 
                {                                        
                    lastDate = fileInfo; 
                    runPackage = true;                 
                }             
                         
            }   
            
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use DateTime and not ints. Something like this:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables["Y:\\Monoday\\Rachael\\PromasterFiles\\Partners YTD Promaster Monthly Transaction list.xlsx"].Value.ToString()); 
        DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(2011, 7, 1);
        Boolean runPackage = false;

        foreach (string currentFile in sourceFiles)             
        {                                  
            DateTime lastModifyDate = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(currentFile);                                                  

            if (lastModifyDate > lastDate)                 
            {                                        
                lastDate = lastModifyDate; 
                runPackage = true;                 
            }             

        }   


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `fileInfo = new fileInfoNew(currentFile)` doesn't make sense.

`fileInfo` and `fileInfoNew` are both `int`s. In particular, `fileInfoNew` is not a type, even though you're trying to use it like one.

It seems like you're trying to get the the most recent file amongst a list of files, but that should be done using `DateTime`s, not `int`s:

```
DateTime lastModifyDate = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(currentFile);
```

Comment: The line is trying to put the last updated date from the file into fileInfo... so from there it can be compared to lastDate..

Comment: have used that line but how do i get lastModifyDate into int to compare it to lastdate?
Thanks for your help :)